# How to give Input in Proper Shape to Keras Embedding Layer?

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, embedding

I am developing LSTM Program for NLP Problem.
Shape of my data and Label is = (10,20,1)

My Model code looks like this :

```
model.add(Embedding(18,17,input_length=20,weights=[embedding_weights])) ( Shape of Embedding (18,17))
# encoder layer
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(20, 1)))

# repeat vector
model.add(RepeatVector(20))

# decoder layer
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I am getting following error

"input_length" is 20, but received input has shape (None, 20, 1)

Comment: Remove the last axis with dimension 1 from the input data (i.e. it should be `(10,20)`, and not `(10,20,1)`). You can do it with `numpy.squeeze(my_data_array, axis=-1)`.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks.
I am still confused like at the end if we are suppose to squeeze the data and remove last axis, then why we are suppose to reshape it initially to 3D ( 10,20,1) in my case ?

Comment: No, you are not supposed to do that (i.e. 3-D shape array). The shape of input data and target values should be compatible with input and output shape of model. You can always run `model.summary()` to find out those values if you are in doubt.